# Event logging system in PHP batching events for db insert

Tags: php, apache

I'm currently working on an event-logging system that will form part of a real-time analytics system. Individual events are sent via rpc from the main application to another server where a separate php script running under apache handles the event data.

Currently the receiving server PHP script hands off the event data to an AMQP exchange/queue from where a Java application pops events from the queue, batches them up and performs a batch db insert.

This will provide great scalability however I'm thinking the cost is complexity.

I'm now looking to simplify things a little so my questions are:

Would it be possible to remove the AMQP queue and perform the batching and inserting of events directly to the db from within the PHP script(s) on the receiving server?

And if so, would some kind of intermediary database be required to batch up the events or could the batching be done from within PHP ?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Thanks for taking the time to respond, to be more specific. Is it possible for a PHP script running under Apache to be configured to handle multiple http requests?

So, as Apache spawns child processes each of these processes would be configured to accept say 1000 http requests, deal with them and then shut down?

Comment: I wonder how this question can be answered by anybody else but your own. Technically everything is possible, but you do not ask about technical possibilities here, so what tho tell?

Answer (score 1):

I see three potential answers to your question:

1. Yes
2. No
3. Probably

If you share metrics of alternative implementations (because everything you ask about is techncially possible so please do it first and then get hard results) we can give better suggestions. But as long as you don't provide some meat, put it on the grill and show us the results, there is not much more to tell.